# IAR Embedded Workbench: Exporting data from Terminal I/O

Tags: iar

I'm currently working on a project in IAR Embedded Workbench, and I've run into a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I have written a program that interacts with hardware to get information from the board to perform calculations. The calculations are correct, and are being printed out to the Terminal I/O from the program.

I would like to know if it's possible to access these calculations for use in a third-party program.

We are expanding on a previous project which utilized additional hardware to send the information to a third-party program, but at this stage, it's not exactly an option.

Does IAR Embedded Workbench store this information somewhere, or are there settings I can reconfigure to allow for exporting data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the full DLIB library, and you run the application in the C-SPY debugger, you can use 'fopen', 'fprintf' and friends to write to a file on the host machine.

This work both when using the IDE or when running in batch mode using 'cspybat'.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [C-SPY Target Access Server](https://github.com/IARSystems/cspy-target-access-demo) to access the target's memory directly from an external application.